# How to convert RealMatrix for use in Apache commons from a created data type?

Tags: java, matrix

I need to add a method using the calculation of the inverse provided by the Apache Commons class `CholeskyDecomposition` using `getSolver().getInverse()`. When I try using `MyMatrix` as the data type it says it needs to be of the type `RealMatrix`, but I'm unsure how to convert between the two (nor do I know why it needs to be a custom data type but it does)

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class MyMatrix
{
    private double[][] matrix;
    public MyMatrix(double[][] m)
    {
        matrix = m;
    }
    public MyMatrix inverseCD(MyMatrix m)
    {
        return CholeskyDecomposition(m).getSolver().getInverse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CholeskyDecomposition` uses a `RealMatrix` interface. You should see what implementation of `RealMatrix` is suitable for your usecase. From your question, it seems to me you can use `Array2DRowRealMatrix`.

You can use it like this:

```
public MyMatrix inverseCD(MyMatrix m)
{
  RealMatrix realMatrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(m.getMatrix()); // assuming you created a getter method for the `double[][]` variable
  double[][] inversed = new CholeskyDecomposition(realMatrix).getSolver().getInverse()
                       .getData();
  return new MyMatrix(inversed);
}
```

Comment: So is m of type double[][] even though it's of the MyMatrix type?

Comment: Thats a mistake in the code. You just need to send appropriate argument there. In your case `double [][]`